# Problem with VIA Technologies, Inc. VL805 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 01)

Tags: drivers, usb-device

I have some problems with VL805. I tried to update the firmware as suggested here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162391/usb-3-0-pci-card.

```
[    2.407086] usb 3-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=1000, bcdDevice=11.00
[    2.407087] usb 3-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.407088] usb 3-1.1: Product: USB DISK
[    2.407088] usb 3-1.1: Manufacturer: SMI Corporation
```

...

```
[    3.415543] usb 3-1-port1: cannot reset (err = -22)
[    3.415547] usb 3-1-port1: cannot reset (err = -22)
[    3.415549] usb 3-1-port1: cannot reset (err = -22)
[    3.415551] usb 3-1-port1: cannot reset (err = -22)
[    3.415552] usb 3-1-port1: cannot reset (err = -22)
[    3.415553] usb 3-1-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
```

...

The card works from BIOS (it can boot from a device plugged into the card). I have disabled iommu in BIOS since there appears to be a known issue with this card and AMD iommu. FYI, CPU virtualization is also turned off. Yet I see

```
[    1.041848] AMD-Vi: IOMMU performance counters supported
[    1.042086] iommu: Adding device 0000:00:01.0 to group 0
```

...

```
[    1.044209] AMD-Vi: Found IOMMU at 0000:00:00.2 cap 0x40
```

Do I have to disable the iommu driver also?

Uname:

```
    Linux 5.0.0-37-lowlatency #40~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu Nov 14 12:51:01 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Machine info:

```
efi: EFI v2.60 by American Megatrends
efi:  ACPI 2.0=0xdd225000  ACPI=0xdd225000  SMBIOS=0xde48b000  ESRT=0xda62cf98  MEMATTR=0xda62b698 
secureboot: Secure boot could not be determined (mode 0)
SMBIOS 2.8 present.
DMI: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. MS-7B79/X470 GAMING PRO (MS-7B79), BIOS 1.10 03/29/2018
CPU0: AMD Ryzen 7 2700X Eight-Core Processor (family: 0x17, model: 0x8, stepping: 0x2)
```

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Root Complex                     
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) I/O Memory Management Unit             
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge           
00:01.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge                   
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 59)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 7
03:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43d0 (rev 01)
03:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c8 (rev 01)
03:00.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c6 (rev 01)
16:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c7 (rev 01)
16:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c7 (rev 01)
16:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c7 (rev 01)
16:03.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c7 (rev 01)
16:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c7 (rev 01)
16:08.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c7 (rev 01)
18:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
1a:00.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VL805 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 01)
1c:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1143 USB 3.1 Host Controller
1d:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB] (rev a1)
1d:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
1e:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 145a
1e:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Platform Security Processor
1e:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] USB 3.0 Host controller
1f:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1455
1f:00.2 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51)
```

lsusb:

```
Bus 008 Device 003: ID 0451:8140 Texas Instruments, Inc. 
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 0451:8140 Texas Instruments, Inc. 
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 007: ID 0451:ca01 Texas Instruments, Inc. 
Bus 007 Device 006: ID 0451:8142 Texas Instruments, Inc. TUSB8041 4-Port Hub
Bus 007 Device 005: ID 0582:01e1 Roland Corp. 
Bus 007 Device 004: ID 258a:0001  
Bus 007 Device 003: ID 1038:1720 SteelSeries ApS 
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 0451:8142 Texas Instruments, Inc. TUSB8041 4-Port Hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 090c:1000 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) Flash Drive
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I need to boot with iommu=soft to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems and was unable to get the VIA VL805 USB 3.0 board working on a AMD Athlon dual core with AMD 780V chipset. Replacing it with a board based on the NEC 720201 chipset solved the problems.

PS: Adding iommu=soft and reboot did not help with this hardware.

Comment: Good answer, but the card I got was the only I could find from a domestic retailer which also featured an internal USB 3.0 header.